# preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation only called once in iOS7 with subclass of UINavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I have subclassed UINavigationController like this:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {

    if (self.topViewController != nil) return [self.topViewController shouldAutorotate];
    else return [super shouldAutorotate];
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {

    if (self.topViewController != nil) return [self.topViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
    else return [super supportedInterfaceOrientations];
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {

    if (self.topViewController != nil) return [self.topViewController preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation];
    else return [super preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation];
}
```

`supportedInterfaceOrientations` and `shouldAutorotate` are called fine in each view controller pushed into the stack, but `preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation` is only called once working with iOS 7. Any ideas to trigger `preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation` when each view controller is loaded will be appreciated =)

Thanks in advance and sorry for my english =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer myself. I subclassed UINavigationController to call the three methods posted in the question before on some view controllers pushed into the stack, to restrict orientation to portrait, landscape or whatever i wanted. The problem was that preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation wasn't called on view controllers and so, they weren't displayed with the orientation i wanted for them. To force iOS to present view controllers in one orientation or another i check the orientation in viewDidLoad and if it is not the orientation i want, i push a temp view controller like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    if([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft || [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight) {

        TempViewController *temp = [[TempViewController alloc] init];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:temp animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Then in TempViewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

The result is that first view controller is displayed with the orientation specified in preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation.  Maybe it's a little tricky and it can't be done using other implementation, but at least this works =)

Answer (score -1):

Hi this is what i'm doing, you can try it:

[shouldAutorotate, supportedInterfaceOrientations and preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation does not work as expected in iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20355089/shouldautorotate-supportedinterfaceorientations-and-preferredinterfaceorientati)

It was a big head ache.

Happy coding.