# shouldAutorotate, supportedInterfaceOrientations and preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation does not work as expected in iOS 7

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, ios7, uitabbarcontroller

I'm having problems trying to block the orientations in some views, but the code is not working property.

I'm using this lines in every view:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    } else {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
    }
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

It almost work in the views that are using the UINavigationController, but in the ones that use the UITabBarController is where i'm having big problems, because it seams that the code is not been called.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ok I solve it, you have to subclass UINavigationController and UITabBarController, so here is the code:

```
//cCustomNavigationController.h file

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface cCustomNavigationController : UINavigationController <UINavigationControllerDelegate>

@end

//cCustomNavigationController.m file

#import "cCustomNavigationController.h"

@interface cCustomNavigationController ()

@end

@implementation cCustomNavigationController 

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return [self.visibleViewController shouldAutorotate];
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return [self.visibleViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
    return [self.visibleViewController preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation];
}

@end

//cCustomTabController.h file

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface cCustomTabController : UITabBarController <UITabBarControllerDelegate>

@end

//cCustomTabController.m file

#import "cCustomTabController.h"

@interface cCustomTabController  ()

@end

@implementation cCustomTabController

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return [self.selectedViewController shouldAutorotate];
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return [self.selectedViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
    return [self.selectedViewController preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation];
}

@end
```

now you just have to create your TabBarController or your NavigationController using this classes where ever you need it i.e.

```
//For the UINavigationController
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[cCustomNavigationController alloc] init];

//For the UITabBarController
UITabBarController *tabController = [[cCustomTabController alloc] init];
```

I hope this help you guys.

Comment: If I am using Storyboards, I only need to set custom class of the view controller in the storyboard to the subclasses, right?