# Subclassing both UITabBarController and UINavigationController

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

Hello I am quite new to iPhone development (working with iOS 7). Basically I want my application to respond to screen rotations (i.e. changing the screen orientation) My project uses both `UITabBarController` and `UINavigationController`. However when I rotate the device it won't call the "`shouldAutorotate`" function in a `ViewController` called `LoginView.m`.

Therefore I have followed the answer in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20355610/2529416) up to the point where it subclasses both `UITabBarController` and `UINavigationController`. Can someone explain to me how to add (i.e reference it)the orientation behaviour within the `LoginView.m` class or to the entire project.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: please elaborate a bit more what you are trying to achieve. it is correct that the `shouldAutorotate` will be called for the root view controller, which in your case, is a TabBarController or a NavigationController, but we need more details on the desired outcome

Comment: @Argent Basically I want to change the screen orientation respect to the screen rotation. I have a view called LoginView.m which extends "UIViewController".  Also I see UITabBarController and UINavigationController properties in my AppDelegate.m. Please help

Comment: if you want your views to autorotate and you are using basic ios controls that should work out of the box. just select the device orientations you want to support in the project file of your app in xcode

Comment: @Argent, I already did that, by including Portrait (bottom home button), Portrait (top home button), Landscape (left home button) and Landscape (right home button) in the plist file but no success. Or is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

In your subclassed UItabbarcontroller

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {

    UINavigationController *navView = (UINavigationController *)[self selectedViewController];
    //Get the selected current tab viewcontroller. I guess you are having a Navigationcontroller    

    UIViewController *vc = [navView.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];  
    //Fetch root viewcontroller of your navigationcontroller

    return [self checkOrientationForViewController:vc];

}

-(BOOL) checkForViewsForViewController : (UIViewController *)vc{

    if([vc isKindOfClass:[FirstViewController class]]){

        FirstViewController *vc1 = (FirstViewController *)vc;

        return [vc1 shouldAutorotate];
    }
    if([vc isKindOfClass:[SecondViewController class]]){

        SecondViewController *vc2 = (SecondViewController *)vc;

        return [vc2 shouldAutorotate];
    }
    if([vc isKindOfClass:[ThirdViewController class]]){

        ThirdViewController *vc3 = (ThirdViewController *)vc;

        return [vc3 shouldAutorotate];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

In respective viewcontrollers implement the shouldAutorotate method

Comment: Thanks for your time. Do I have to reference it in the AppDelegate file to notify the app that I am using these custom classes?

Comment: Yes you have to import it AppDelegate

Comment: Could you please tell me how to do it?, that's where I am confused. Thanks again

Comment: Can you just explain it a bit more. What do you want exactly.

Comment: How can I reference the subclassed UItabbarcontroller within the AppDelegate.m and also within a specific controller? (in my case LoginView.m). Im quite new to iPhone development.Please help

Comment: When you launch the tab bar controller assign the the tabbarcontroller  object to a object in appdelegate. The you can get the tabbarobject in appdelegate and you fetch the respective vc like i mentioned previously

Comment: ok, so do I have to include that code in the "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" method of AppDelegate.m? could you please post the code or direct me to an example?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of subclassing, is worth to know that there are also delegate methods, in UINavigationcontroller and UITabbarController that make you handle rotations at runtime:

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)navigationControllerPreferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation:(UINavigationController *)navigationController
```

[Ref doc.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UINavigationControllerDelegate/navigationControllerSupportedInterfaceOrientations:)

```
- (NSUInteger)tabBarControllerSupportedInterfaceOrientations:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController
```

[Ref doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITabBarControllerDelegate/tabBarControllerSupportedInterfaceOrientations:).

Evenf if Apple has removed the advice to do not subclass Nav and Tabbar controller, using delegation will be the most reliable solution over time

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Delegation you can also use

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
```

UINavigationController and UITabBarController ask their child view controllers which interface orientations they support. So you can implement "- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations" in your LoginView.m and return the appropriate interface orientations.

You also need to edit your Info.plist and add the supported interface orientations their. You can do this with Xcode by opening the project view. Also have a look at [Apples documentation on supporting interface orientations](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges.html)