# How to setting orientation for each ViewController in Tabbed Application in iOS7?

Tags: ios7, rotation

In the Tabbed Application I have two View.

I want to fix the firstView to portrait and the seccondView can rotate to portrait and landscape.

I implement the code below in firstViewController.

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientation {
   return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

The code in secondViewController is

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientation {
   return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
}
```

But when I rotate my phone, the setting have no working.

Cloud somebody can tell my how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to subclass your UINavigationController and UITabBarController. Take a look at this questions, it is essentially the same [shouldAutorotate, supportedInterfaceOrientations and preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation does not work as expected in iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20355089/shouldautorotate-supportedinterfaceorientations-and-preferredinterfaceorientati)